# Type 'import("/@types/chart.js/index.d.ts")' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

I have an issue in my angular app.

I installed `chart.js` and `chartjs-plugin-datalabels` library via `npm`, I created my charts and it works correctly, but when I try to deploy the app the console shows the following error:

> error TS2740: Type 'import("/node_modules/@types/chart.js/index.d.ts")' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.
>   error TS2322: Type 'import("/node_modules/@types/chart.js/index.d.ts")' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.

I tried different methods to resolve this problem but the issue remains, here is my code:

```
import * as Chart from 'chart.js';
import 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';

this.ReceivedChart = new Chart('received', {
            type: 'line',
            data:{
              labels:this.LabelsData,
              datasets:[
                {
                  data:this.ReceivedData,
                  borderColor: "#3cba9f",
                  fill: false,
                  label:'Received'
                }
              ]
            },
            options: {
              plugins: {
                datalabels: {
                   display: true,
                   align: 'top',
                   anchor: 'end',
                   rotation:90
                }
             },
              legend: {
                display: true
              },
              scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                  display: true,
                  ticks: {
                    autoSkip: false,
                    maxRotation: 90,
                    minRotation: 90
                  }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                  display: true
                }],
              }
            }
        });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should import `Chart` from `chart.js` via `import { Chart } from 'chart.js';`

Comment: Thanks for your time to answer mi question, 
I had previously imported it as you mentioned it, but I had the same error

Comment: Can you give details on the version of `chart.js` and `@types/chart.js` that you have installed? Also, what type is `this.ReceivedChart`? If I test this locally and give a variable the type `any[]` and then try to assign a chart to that, I see this same type of error. Make sure it is of type `Chart`.

Comment: chart.js@2.8.0 - @types/chart.js@2.7.51. ReceivedChart is declared as "ReceivedChart = [];"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared your `ReceivedChart` as an empty array and thus have given it the type `any[]`.

```js
this.ReceivedChart = []; // TypeScript infers the type to be any[] here
```

In your code you are creating a new chart and setting it to this variable.

```js
this.ReceivedChart = new Chart(...);
```

TypeScript is complaining because you are setting a `Chart` object to what it is expecting to be an array. You will either need to set up your variable to be of type `Chart` (which you are attempting to set it to) or you will need to push the chart you just created onto your array.

```js
this.ReceivedChart.push(new Chart(...));
```